# Can't reset my Azure VM's remote desktop password

Tags: azure, rdp

A client of our has lost their RDP password for an Azure virtual machine and I'm trying to recover it. I've run through the steps outlined in this article:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/06/26/microsoft-azure-virtual-machines-reset-forgotten-admin-password-with-windows-powershell.aspx

but still cannot connect to the machine. All I get is a message saying "*Your credentials did not work*".

It's my understanding that I've just set the credentials, so why is there a problem?

The password I'm using is 10 characters, and contains a mixture of upper case, numbers, letters and symbols. So I don't think it's a strong password issue.

I've also tried using the AzureVMAccessExtension. I followed the steps outlined in that to reset the admin password as well as tried creating a new account. Neither of these has worked. I get the same error as above.

I can't scrap the VM since it has software running on it in production. So to detach and reattach to a new VM is not an option.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get access to this VM or why the powershell scripts are not working for me?

Answer (score 3):

With the new preview portal, you can gain access to Azure VM by using the new Password Reset    feature (life-saver when you forgot your VM password). It will create a new admin user to the existing VM.

Navigate to Browse All (Left Side Menu)-> Virtual Machines (Classic) ->
 Click on the Target Virtual machine -> Select "All Settings" -> Password Reset

[image]

Comment: Currently the new portal says "Reset Password...Coming soon"?